# Sharepoint Server Farm Project - Where do I start?

Tags: sharepoint-server, server-farm, sql-server-2016

I am doing a class project where we are deploying Sharepoint on a server farm technically(Virtual Machines). It will be used to have an IT ticketing system. One of us is doing SQL, one of us is doing Active Directory, one of us is doing Exchange,one of us is doing Sharepoint. We aren't given any instructions on how to achieve this.

I'm doing the Active Directory portion and so far I have DNS, IIS, and Active Directory installed. I do not have Active Directory Certificates portion installed yet.

We are using Windows Server 2016.

For this, I'm not really sure where to run at first. If you guys have any resources you could link me to that would be lovely, or an idea of what I should start configuring first server role wise. Or the kind of things I may have to enable so that my other group mates and get their stuff to work with mine.

I don't need you guys giving me a step by step. Just a general idea of where to start. This project is pretty daunting, especially since it's group work. I've never had to do something of this caliber.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it is 2 step project.

1. You have to install and configure SharePoint farm
2. You have to develop Ticketing system.

For the 1st part.

1. you need to select the topology of you farm...how many server and what role. You can get more information [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485(v=office.16).aspx):
2. You have to meet the hardware and software requirent which are mention [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485(v=office.16).aspx):
3. Now you need to install the SharePoint and configure.[you can read more here.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262957(v=office.16).aspx)

You can also use the script to install SharePoint using autospinstaller (famous in SharePoint world).

Once you have your SharePoint farm up and ready then you can develop your ticketing system.

This is good solution for SharePoint 2013 but give u a starting point.

Here is good example [Trouble Ticket - Helpdesk Template for SharePoint 2013](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Trouble-Ticket-Template-7a699eda)

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/create-service-desk-ticketing-system-sharepoint-laurent-butre

[1](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485(v=office.16).aspx):Trouble Ticket - Helpdesk T https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt346114(v=office.16).aspx